# Counting question - arranging in a line

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Say I want to arrange (k-1) of the letter 'G' and (k-1) of the letter 'L' in a line such that for the *n* th letter 'L', there must be at least (n+1) 'G's before it somewhere in the line. (sort of like a bank balance not being allowed to reach 0, G being gain a dollar and L being lose a dollar). How many ways can I do so?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Do you always have the same number of G and L? How about listing the number of possibilities when the number is small? For example, the only possibility is GL for 1. GLGL, GGLL for 2, etc.